# Fast symmetric binary matrix multiplication using vector extensions

Tags: c++, gcc, vectorization, intrinsics

I'm using a binary matrix representing an undirected graph and toying with gcc's vector extensions to see what can be done to produce a matrix product (replacing +/* operations with |/&) efficiently.

The following attempt assumes both input matrices are symmetric about the diagonal:

```
typedef unsigned char __attribute__((vector_size(8))) vec;
vec example_input = {
  0b11001000
, 0b11001001
, 0b00100100
, 0b00010000
, 0b11001000
, 0b00100100
, 0b00000010
, 0b01000001
};

void symmetric_product( const vec& left, const vec& right, vec& result ) {
  for( unsigned ii = 0; ii < 8; ++ii ) {
    vec tmp{};
    // broadcast row ii across all rows
    tmp -= 1;
    tmp &= left[ii];
    // compute first half of dot product of
    // all rows in 'right' with row 'ii'
    tmp &= right;
    // The rest does the 'tallying'; I believe
    // the rest could be replaced with the
    // pext intrinsic
    result[ii] = 0;
    for( unsigned jj = 0; jj < 8; ++jj ) {
      result[ii] |= (0 != tmp[ii]) << jj;
    }
  }
}
```

I was researching something similar several months back and thought I'd seen a slick way to pull this off, but all I'm finding now is the pext* family of instructions.

If that's the only way then so be it; my hope is someone knows of another way that doesn't require hardware-specific intrinsics.

Comment: Related: [Large (0,1) matrix multiplication using bitwise AND and popcount instead of actual int or float multiplies?](//stackoverflow.com/q/45376006).  But that's using popcount instead of OR to replace `+` to accumulate row*column dot-product results.  Some of the same things apply, and bit-transposing large chunks becomes more important (because your result will be packed bits, not integer counts).

Comment: I think you definitely want to find a way to be using wide AND and OR operations to do 64 or 128/256/512 bits in parallel with each operation.  Striding down 512 columns in parallel might not be terrible, as long as it's aligned so you read a whole cache line of columns before moving on to the next row.  Or does that even work without a transpose?  Maybe you need to broadcast a single bit to all positions in a vector.  Been a while since I looked at matmul, but there are ways to optimize it that loop over an output row multiple times, instead of doing one row X column dot product at once.

Comment: Agreed.  When I'm done this won't be limited to the simpler 8x8 case, but for the moment I'm just trying to get a feel for how to do it + do it correctly before I generalize.  re: transposing, since I'm working with undirected graphs the matrices will always be symmetric, so transpose won't be needed.

Comment: There are really two separate domains: the small problem where multiple rows fit into one vector, vs. the large problem where one vector isn't wide enough for a single row.  Where it's a question of shuffle throughput for rearranging bytes (and even bits) for small problems, vs. cache throughput for the large case (where the cost of broadcasting 1 bit is amortized over using it for multiple vectors for a whole row.)

Comment: See https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf / [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory?](//stackoverflow.com/a/47714514) appendix A for a regular cache-blocked matmul, broadcasting one element at a time from a column vector, and looping over contiguous rows in the destination and other source.  (So 2 loads + 1 store per mul/add, or per AND/OR in your case).  In a scalar, you can broadcast a bit by left-shifting it to the top and then arithmetic right shift.

Comment: For a big array, maybe branch on individual column bits because `0 & anything = 0` (skip the row) or `1 & x = x` so you can skip the AND and just load from the src row and OR it into the result.  But that's only useful if looping over a single row costs something close to the branch-miss cost.

Comment: For my use case I only need up to perhaps 32x32.  While I would certainly enjoy putting together something more general, my free time is rather limited :)